# WSO2 identify user subscriber in server side

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to add headers to the request that wso2 sends to the endpoint of the final application, using custom policies uploader. Using this, I have been able to add a custom header with the value of the SYSTIME property for example.
Are there any properties I can add in this way that refer to the subscribed user, token or username that the service consumes?
I need to identify the user subscriber of wso2 from the final application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the backend JWT token to send the end-user information to the backend. This will be a JWT and the default header is X-JWT-Assertion.

Please follow the documentation[1] on how to enable this.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/#passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt